# How to run Java project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, offline-browsing

A friend of mine once gave me a Java project on offline browser.  It contains all class file as well as  Java sources but I don't know how to run it or how can I check how it works . It doesn't contain any database or applet. please help

Comment: there are many possible types of java code to run. could you provide more details? may be you have source files as well?

Comment: Is the project a web app or a stand alone java project?

Comment: The sources are importing Java. swing.

Comment: The project is a folder containing all class files only. I tried opening project in net beans as well as Eclipse but they show empty folder

Comment: possible because they need correct folder structure .

Comment: you should find class which contain main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a java `.class` file, open the terminal (if you are using Unix machine) or the command line (if you are using a Windows machine) and type `java filename`

**Note:** `filename` does not include the `.class` extension, just use the name of the file and do not include the extension. 
If you get an error this probably means you don't have java installed.

Comment: it's a collection of. class file don't know which one will be the main file

Comment: Cool, if you still can't find the main class file and you are on a Unix machine (Mac or Linux) try running this command: `grep main *.java`. You are looking for the file with `public static void main(String[] args)` in it. If you don't find it you may have to ask your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Import it into Eclipse or NetBeans and then click "run"...

That would be the simplest solution in my mind